# Adding text to a rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

Wants to add text to a following rectangle. Also wants draw an another rectangle on the right side of the following rectangle sharing the boundary.

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}


\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows,shadows,patterns,calc}


\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    %\centering
%   \captionsetup{justification = centering}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5mm,y=0.5mm]
        \coordinate (a1);
        \coordinate[right=150 of a1](a2);
        \coordinate[below=90 of a1](a3);
        \coordinate[right=150 of a3](a4);   
        \draw[ultra thick,rounded corners=10,green] ($(a4)-(80,20)$) 
rectangle +(80*2,20*2);%Rectangle rounded       
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Adaptations:**

- Remove unused packages, unused tikzlibraries and add needed package (`tikz`).
- (Old: Add `node{\Large text}` right after `rectangle` to add text centered or just use nodes as follows ...)
- Use `node` to draw the rectangular nodes with text, so you don't need to calculate any coordinates.
- You can set `minimum width=160, minimum height=40` to the desired size.
- To let node B share the right boundary of A you can set option `right=0 of a`.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
            myrectangle/.style={rectangle, draw, minimum width=160, minimum height=40, ultra thick, rounded corners=10, green}
        ]

            \node[myrectangle] (a) at (0,0) {\Large text};
            \node[myrectangle, right=0 of a] (b) {\Large B};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=4mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every fit/.style={inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, draw}]
\begin{scope}[yshift=2cm,y=0.8cm]
\node [fit={(0,0) (4,1)}, label=center:{first rectangle}] {};
\node [fit={(4,0) (8,1)}, label=center:{second rectangle}] {};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

small variation of [dexteritas](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/123129/dexteritas) answer:

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
    \begin{figure}[htb]
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
            node distance=0pt,
            every node/.style={draw=green, ultra thick, rounded corners=10,
                               minimum width=0.5\linewidth, minimum height=40, outer sep=0pt,
                               font=\large\bfseries, text=red}
                            ]

            \node (n1) {A};
            \node [right=of n1] {B};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

width of both nodes are equal to width one text column:

[image]